# I can't determine why this list-duplicate-removal code in Python doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, list, duplicates, iteration

I have found a better way to do this, so that's not my main issue. I'm trying to just determine why what I have below here *doesn't* work and I just can't. Any advice?

```
def removeDuplicates(l):
    for item in l:
        while l.count(item) > 1:
            l.remove(item)
    return l
```

Thanks!

Comment: Mutating the list while iterating over it. Also, strange indentation.

Comment: I figured that was the problem, that I was changing the list while editing it, but it seemed to work for a few test cases I tried. Why exactly doesn't it work?

Comment: Some related content [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating).